# sql: Part a string in all the substrings separated by a specific character and create that many columns in the output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to achieve something like the below output with postgres sql, assuming a table like below:

| id | pathway |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | NULL |
| 4 | B | A |

And I would like the output to be like:

| id | pathway_A | pathway_B | pathway_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | B | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | A | B | NULL |

I would like to highlight that:

1. The real pathways are more than A, B, C in my data.
2. The pathways are not following a specific order (for example: a row
   might have `D | G| X |A`  and another row might have `A | X| D |G` , so the order is totally random).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.26.1.1.1) to split the strings, [`trim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.5.2.2.3.1.1.1) to clean them up, then [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.2.1.1.1) to re-collect them into proper arrays, on which [`array_position() is not null`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.8.1.1.1) can check for presence of distinct fields. To pivot that into your final result you can use [`crosstab()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS-CROSSTAB-N-TEXT) from `tablefunc` extension.

If the list of distinct fields is static, you can just extract it and use to construct your `crosstab()` query. If it's dynamic, you'll need to use dynamic SQL in PL/pgSQL routine. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/1d3R_nGP)

```
create table test (id serial, pathway text);
insert into test(pathway) values
('A|B'),('B'),(NULL),('B|A'),
(' D | G| X |A  '),('A | X| D |G');

select '"pathway_'||
       string_agg(distinct field,'" bool, "pathway_' order by field)||
       '" bool' AS column_list
from (select trim(regexp_split_to_table(pathway,'\|')) field from test)_;
```

| column_list |
| --- |
| "pathway_A" bool, "pathway_B" bool, "pathway_D" bool, "pathway_G" bool, "pathway_X" bool |

```
create extension tablefunc;

select * 
from crosstab($s1$ 
with 
 element_fields as (
    select distinct id, trim(regexp_split_to_table(pathway,'\|')) field from test)
,field_arrays as (
  select id,array_agg(field order by field)field_array 
  from element_fields group by 1) 
,distinct_fields as (
  select distinct field from element_fields)
,field_presence as (
  select a.id, b.field, array_position(field_array,b.field) is not null presence
  from field_arrays a,distinct_fields b)
select id, field, presence
from field_presence
order by 1,2 $s1$)
AS ct(id int, "pathway_A" bool, "pathway_B" bool, "pathway_D" bool, "pathway_G" bool, "pathway_X" bool);
```

| id | pathway_A | pathway_B | pathway_D | pathway_G | pathway_X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t | t | f | f | f |
| 2 | f | t | f | f | f |
| 4 | t | t | f | f | f |
| 5 | t | f | t | t | t |
| 6 | t | f | t | t | t |

If the elements in pathways can change (more options can appear later), you'll need the dynamic SQL procedure to adjust the crosstab column output specification accordingly. If you really need to, you can use a `case` statement to also translate the `boolean` `true`/`false` values indicating whether the field was present in a `pathway` of a given `id`, into the field name or `null` like you showed in your example.

```
insert into test(pathway) values ('E|H | Y'),('Z');
```

```
create procedure pivot_test_table(output_table text)language plpgsql AS $f$
begin execute format(
    $dynamic_sql$
        drop table if exists %1$I cascade;
        create table %1$I as select * 
        from crosstab(
            $crosstab_query$ 
            with 
             element_fields as (
              select distinct id, trim(regexp_split_to_table(pathway,'\|')) 
              field from test)
            ,field_arrays as (
              select id,array_agg(field order by field)field_array 
              from element_fields group by 1) 
            ,distinct_fields as (
              select distinct field from element_fields)
            ,field_presence as (
              select a.id, 
                     b.field, 
                     array_position(field_array,b.field) is not null is_present
              from field_arrays a,distinct_fields b)
            select id, field, case when is_present then field end
            from field_presence
            order by 1,2 
            $crosstab_query$)
        AS ct(id int, %2$s);
    $dynamic_sql$, 
    output_table,
    (  select '"pathway_'||
              string_agg(distinct field,'" text, "pathway_' order by field)||
              '" text'
       from (select trim(regexp_split_to_table(pathway,'\|')) field from test)_)
); end $f$;
```

```
call pivot_test_table('pivot_test_table_result');
select * from pivot_test_table_result order by 1;
```

| id | pathway_A | pathway_B | pathway_D | pathway_E | pathway_G | pathway_H | pathway_X | pathway_Y | pathway_Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | *null* | B | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | A | B | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | A | *null* | D | *null* | G | *null* | X | *null* | *null* |
| 6 | A | *null* | D | *null* | G | *null* | X | *null* | *null* |
| 7 | *null* | *null* | *null* | E | *null* | H | *null* | Y | *null* |
| 8 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | Z |